# Database query for fetching products in customer cart programmatically

Tags: php, mysql, magento

How to build a query for fetching all the product details from magento customer cart,

actually we have tried

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$quote->setSharedStoreIds($storeIds)->loadByCustomer($customer);

foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) { 

            $product = $item->getProduct(); 
            $productsResult[] = array(// Basic product data
             'product_id' => $product->getId()
}
```

but the issue is we are not getting proper data as we are expecting, if we able to found this **database query** so it would be better

Comment: Try `$quote->getAllVisibleItems()`

Comment: we have already tried this! still facing issue, if able to query then it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProductId();
}
```

Comment: we have already tried this! still facing issue, if able to query then it would be helpful

Comment: @SagarPanchal Can you explain the result you are expecting and the result you are getting. Share screenshot.

Comment: we have developed API for add to cart, while adding to cart VIA API, product is properly adding to cart and its properly displaying on site, but while getting this all details in API, CONFIGURABLE products not displaying its options

Comment: @SagarPanchal To display selected options use $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct()) within the loop. This will return an array

Comment: `$options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($product);` tried already

Answer (score 0):

The code below is perfectly working for me

```
<?php
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$items = $quote->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProductId();
    $options = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct());
    print_r($options);
}
?>
```